# Problem with placing "first" array's value into the "second". C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

So I recently started to learn C# with "C# The player's guide" book (a week or so). And I stumbled upon the loops, which I'm having difficult time to understand. But still. Got this interesting task:

"**Copying an Array**. Write code to create a copy of an array. First, start by creating an initial array. (You can use whatever type of data you want.)  Let’s start with 10 items. Declare an array variable and assign it a new array with 10 items in it. Use the things we’ve discussed to put some values in the array. Now create a second array variable. Give it a new array with the same length as the first. Instead of using a number for this length, use the Length property to get the size of the original array. Use a loop to read values from the original array and place them in the new array. Also print out the contents of both arrays, to be sure everything copied correctly."

And this is my code.

```
char[] firstArray = new char[10] { 'x', 'g', 'z', 'd', 'b', 'n', 'f', 's', 'h', 'e' };
        char[] secondArray = new char[firstArray.Length];

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            secondArray = firstArray.GetValue(1);

            Console.WriteLine(secondArray);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong, and help me with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should replace `firstArray.GetValue(1)` with `firstArray[i]`

Comment: Also `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)` with `for (i = 0; i <(firstArray.Length) ; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
char[] firstArray = new char[10] { 'x', 'g', 'z', 'd', 'b', 'n', 'f', 's', 'h', 'e' };
char[] secondArray = new char[firstArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
{
    secondArray[i] = firstArray[i];
}

Console.WriteLine(secondArray);
Console.ReadLine();
```